# How to change the look of angular2 mutiselect dropdown when all items are selected?

Tags: angular, user-interface, multi-select

I am using a multi select dropdown for selecting a bunch of values from a filter type. For some admin like users, it is supposed to select all the filter values by default.
When I do that, I see all 28 values selected in the selection bar as expected.
However, it looks pretty ugly.
Is there a way to display something like "28 of 28 selected" or "All values selected" instead of displaying all 28 values by modifying some attributes of the dropdown?
Thanks in advance! Any response is appreciated :)

Edit: Adding more info for clarity. The dropdown may look something like this

[image: Snapshot of my multi select dropdown with many items selected]

Now where I am seeing the name of countries selected I require just a single tab saying "5 countries selected".

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown values are in array right? You can use template string for showing the array length in the template. {{options.length}} of {{options.length}} are selected.